# 'Backwards' public/private key encryption in C#, how would I go about this?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I want my client side application to be able to decrypt some data generated server side, but not be able to encrypt data such that it can decrypt it again.

So the server can encrypt and decrypt, client can only decrypt.

RSA can't be used for this obviously, as having the private key (to decrypt) means you have to also have the public key.

I need to be able to ensure that the data I'm receiving from the server really did come from the server and wasn't generated by a third party. Giving the client application the public key would mean you couldn't do this.

Any advise on the best way to approach this would be most welcome.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can update your own question by editing it. You can vote for questions (upvote or downvote) and if you get the answer that satisfies your needs and answers your question, you can mark it as an answer

Answer (score 4):

Simple: You encrypt with the private key, then anyone can decrypt with the public key.  This is the basis of certificate signing.

Normally you would encrypt only a hash, and not the entire data block, since this is faster.

- [`RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5hd499h.aspx)
- [`CreateSignature` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t695azzk.aspx)

Comment: Such comments then lead to erroneous questions of "how do I encrypt using private key". Signing, which the OP is asking about, is called *signing*, and not "encryption with private key".

Comment: @Eugene: *signing* is encrypting a *hash* with a private key, to create a *message authentication code*.  Encrypting the entire message with the private key is a viable alternative, and eliminates problems with hash collisions (although replay attacks are still a threat, among others).  The low-level function of encryption works with whatever key you hand it, it's only the fancy wrappers that automatically choose the public key for "encryption".

Comment: (a) not all signing algorithms allow encryption (eg.DSA), (b) encrypting the whole data with asymmetric key is in almost all cases a bad idea due to low speed and necessity to process data in blocks (and split/merge them), (c) practically most frameworks won't allow encryption with private key. Conclusion: that was not the best advice.

Comment: @Eugene: I don't understand your beef with my answer.  It discusses encrypting a hash, for speed.  And it mentions the term *signing*.

Comment: If we skip the part about "basis", there's no word about signing with private key. You talk about encryption 3 times (encrypt, decrypt, encrypt). Well, I don't care much, but as I said such answers lead people to mistake in future, when they attempt to implement "encryption with private key".

Comment: @Eugene: If he was providing a generic answer, yes, but it is C#.NET specific and the RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter and CreateSignature constructor and methods were provided.

Comment: They actually encrypt the hash because there is a limit on the length of data you can encrypt with asymmetric algorithms.   So, yes, it is a signature but it doesn't protect the data if it is a large data set.  Usually the client creates a symmetric key, encrypts it with the server's public key, and tells the server to encrypt responses using that symmetric key.  Check out Diffie-Hellman key exchange. Also, the server encrypts using its private key so the client can decrypt using the server's public key when verifying the signature.

Comment: @Nathan: The symmetric key encrypted with RSA doesn't work so well for signing.  Anyone can decrypt the key, write a new message, encrypt it with the original symmetric key, and send.

Comment: @Ben: I didn't say anything about using a symmetric key for signing.  I explained how it is used to protect the data.

Answer (score 0):

Create two RSA keypairs - one (A) for encryption (and put the private key to the client-side application) and another (B) for *signing* (private key is kept on the server). Now when you send the data to the client, encrypt it using the public key from keypair A and sign it using the private key from keypair B. Signing is done by calculating a cryptographic signature over the hash of the data (to make processing easier and increase it's speed). Signing is normally not done over the data itself due to very low speed of asymmetric cryptography.

This procedure is standard and is supported by all RSA implementations (if the are worth at least a penny). If you plan to use X.509 certificates, then PKCS#7 (later evolved to CMS and to CAdES) standard is your friend. If you go with plain RSA keys, then you will need to invent your own format (but that's not a big hassle).

There's one thing to consider though: you are passing the private key to the application, which means that it becomes available to the user as well and leakage of data is possible that way. Did you consider this side effect?